# ¿Cómo recuperar base de datos sin acceso a localhost ni phpmyadmin en xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp, localhost

He encontrado en StackOverflow ingles, preguntas similares pero muy distintas al tema, en las preguntas y respuestas encontradas describen sobre recuperar base de datos pero desde un instalador de MySQL, instalado directamente, sin uso de xampp. Por lo cual la rutas de las indicaciones son muy diferentes y distintas.

Espero esta pregunta sea bienvenida, nadie esta salvo de este problema :(

Han instalado un sistema de control de cámaras que utiliza la misma ruta localhost, por lo tanto, no puedo acceder.

¿Cómo puedo recuperar las base de datos de manera manual desde las carpetas xampp?